# Let $a,b>0$. Evaluate $\int _{x=0}^{a}\int _{y=0}^{b}e^{max\{b^2x^2,a^2y^2\}} dydx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Let $a,b>0$. Evaluate $\displaystyle\int _{x=0}^{a}\displaystyle\int _{y=0}^{b}e^{\max\{b^2x^2,a^2y^2\}} dydx$.

My work: let $R$ be the rectangle $0\leq x\leq a,0\leq y\leq b$. Then the integral is equivalent to $\displaystyle\int_{R} e^{f(x,y)}$, where $f(x,y)$ is $\max\{b^2x^2,a^2y^2\}$. 
Divide the rectangle in half by the diagonal from $(0,0)$ to $(a,b)$. The required integral is twice the integral over the lower half of $e^{g(x)}$, where $g(x)=b^2x^2$. But integrating over $y$ gives a factor $\frac{bx}{a}$ and the integration over $x$ gives $\dfrac{e^{a^2b^2}-1}{2ab}$. So the required value is $\dfrac{e^{a^2b^2}-1}{ab}$. Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work is correct. I got the same result. 
Lower triangle: we have that
$$\int _{x=0}^{a}\left(\int _{y=0}^{bx/a}e^{b^2x^2} dy\right)dx=\frac{b}{a}\int _{x=0}^{a}e^{b^2x^2}xdx=\dfrac{e^{a^2b^2}-1}{2ab}.$$
Upper triangle: by symmetry,
$$\int _{y=0}^{b}\left(\int _{x=0}^{ay/b}e^{a^2y^2} dx\right)dy=\frac{a}{b}\int _{y=0}^{b}e^{a^2y^2}ydy=\dfrac{e^{a^2b^2}-1}{2ab}.$$
Therefore
$$\displaystyle\int _{x=0}^{a}\displaystyle\int _{y=0}^{b}e^{\max\{b^2x^2,a^2y^2\}} dydx=\dfrac{e^{a^2b^2}-1}{ab}.$$